# How to pass sensitive data from FreeMarker to JavaScript without exposing it in the browser

Tags: javascript, frontend, freemarker, javascript-security

I'm getting a secure private key by executing server-side function in freemarker template. I have to pass the private key to other javascript file but the key is exposed in the DOM during the initial rendering of a FreeMarker template.

I want to prevent exposing it in the DOM and make sure that the generation function is not executed until it's explicitly called, keeping the secure value hidden from the DOM. Please let me know if there's any way to pass this secure key privately from freemarker to JS file.

My code in the **default.ftl** is below

```
<#include "../...">
..
..

<#assign> ...</#assign>

<html>
    <head>
        <script>
           /*generateSecureValue is the server-side function */
            const getSecureValue = () => '${generateSecureValue()}'
        </script>
    </head>
...
...
</html>
```

In the above code generateSecureValue is immediately executed and is exposed in the DOM. I cn only execute this function in freemarker template. How do i share this securely to other child components in javascript?

Comment: The API call that requires a secure key should be made from the server, not from the client, so this problem shouldn't come up.

Comment: If the API requires both front-end and back-end calls, there should be separate keys for each. The front-end key doesn't do anything critical, so it's OK to expose it. Payment processors like Stripe work like this.

Comment: Why can you only generate that function on freemarker?  Why can't you redo the function in the backend code?

Comment: @Barmar it's for generating nonce which comes from server, which i need to append nonce in the JS file for a dynamic script call

Comment: @Flacuchentxox it's for generating nonce which comes from server, which i need to append nonce in the JS file for a dynamic script call